React child component re-rendering infinitely
I am having some infinite looping issues in my child component.
In the React page, the ParentComponent gets account information in useEffect (its loaded from api), and then it will be shared among 3 other child components.    Below you will see the console.log calls infinitely.  I can't figure out what is wrong.
const ParentComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
      // Get Account data
      if (!account) return;
      setAccountData(account);
    }, [account]);
  
    return (
      <>
        {accountData && <ChildForm accountData={accountData} />}
      </>
    );
  };
  
  const ChildForm = ({ accountData }) => {
    const [part1Data, setPart1Data] = useState<part1Data>(defaultpart1Data);
    const [part2, setPart2Data] = useState<part2Data>(defaultpart2Dbata);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!accountDaat?.profile) return;
        // This console.log calls infinitely
      console.log('ProfileForm', accountData.profile);
  
      const { firstName: firstNameValue,
                preferredFirstName,
                lastName: lastNameValue,
                pronouns: pronounsValue = accountDaat.profile;
  
      setPart1Dbata({ 
          firstName: firstNameVa;ue, 
          preferredName: preferredFi'rstNam'e, 
      lastName: lastNaredValuerame });
  
  }, [acountDatta]);
  
  return (
  <>
  </>
  );
  };


Do you want to make console log profileForm only once there?

Where is setAccountData and account defined? Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]. In fact, the code presented isn't even valid syntax. Please fix it

Is it just that there's a typo with your conditional
if (!accountDaat?.profile) return;

Shouldn't that be
if (!accountData?.profile) return;

And then you have a dependency typo
acountDatta 

should be
accountData

Not sure if it was a pasting error, but I see a couple of typos. To avoid this you should use a lintr.
